# Why my flash is not getting the JSON data from a server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security

I am creating a flash project where I load data from server. When I run that from flash software using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or create **exe** then that works but when  I run swf normally or using a browser then it is not working.

I tried to add this code but not working

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("policy.xml");
or
Security.allowDomain("192.168.10.8");
Security.allowDomain("www.example.com");
```

My policy.xml is

```
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
    <allow-access-from domain="www.example.com" /> 
    <allow-access-from domain="192.168.10.8" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**Please advice me.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Flash will initially try to get the flash policy from a different port (843). See this:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not try use URLlaoder? and set up a web with service call.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html

Comment: I loaded data using URLloader but question is about security.

Comment: well you can encrypt the data or have log in set up.

Comment: show this error Error #2028. Do you any answer on this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254183/flash-securityerror-error-2028-local-with-filesystem-swf-file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try LoaderContext class. Here is example code:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/json_file_path.json"), new LoaderContext(true));
```