# Flash sandbox not enabling me getting JSON data from server - AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, sandbox

i'm setting up a **local SWF file** that has to display some **JSON** data retrieved **from a remote web server** in some dynamic text fields.
Code:

```
Security.allowDomain("api.yourserver.com");

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://api.yourserver.com/yourendpoint");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
request.contentType = "application/json";

loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, decodeJSON);

function decodeJSON(event:Event):void{
var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
var Info:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);
cont.textfield1.text = Info.text.field1;
cont.textfield2.text = Info.text.field2;
cont.textfield3.text = Info.text.field3;
}
```

Control > Test - It works. When run standalone it doesn't. I get the 2028 error (sandbox violation).

What i tried:

- The LoaderContext method explained [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239041/why-my-flash-is-not-getting-the-json-data-from-a-server) but i get a 2124 error (Loaded file is an unknown type - seems like the Loader method can only be used with stuff like SWF or medias like JPG etc.);
- Setting local playback as described [always here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254183/flash-securityerror-error-2028-local-with-filesystem-swf-file) but it didn't help;
- Setting up and exception in the Global Flash Player Trust directory as explained [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c95.html) but got the 2028 again;

Anyone who was able to overcome this and willing to explain how or at least pointing in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your current published file has just assess to local files only and not network ones, that's why you got security `#2028` error.

To avoid that, you can change the `Local playback security` for your published swf from the `Publish Settings` to `Access network only` :

[image]

If you still get security errors when testing locally ( like #2048 error ), take a look on [my answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719316/2256820) to add your local swf file to the trusted locations ...

Hope that can help.

Comment: The latter actually made it.

The first solution you depicted was not the correct one, as i tried it already to change and switch back and the fort. I have to admit, that the way you depicted on how to add Global Trust directories is way more efficient than what is explained in Adobe's official guide.

A hearty thank you!